# 20 Questions Game - Switch Statement

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, switch-statement

I have been given the task of creating a 20 Questions game, using C++, where the user thinks of a number between 1 and 100 then the computer will guess it. In order to do this I have been trying to learn how to use the switch statement as I feel this will help me in my main code. However, I cannot seem to get it to work down to the constant error of an illegal break in the code. I have tried changing the code and looking online for answers however I have not been able to find any. My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
    {
    int i;
    cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    cin >> i;
    switch (int i)
    {
        case i > 1 :
        {
            cout << "int greater than 1, less than 5"; endl;
            break;
        }
        case i > 5 :
        {
            cout << "int greater than 5 less than 10"; endl;
            break; 
        }
        case i > 10 :
        {
            cout << "int greater than 10"; endl;
            break; 
        }
    }
    system("PAUSE");
        return 0;

}
```

And the error that shows is:

```
error C2043: illegal break
```

If anyone could help me to answer why these errors keep on showing it would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Ah, welcome to the world of "the C `switch` statement doesn't behave like I wish it would."  You will return many times.

Comment: The C++ language does not allow relational comparator operators in the `case` statements.  The value in a `case` statement must be a constant.

Comment: Does your assignment requires exactly 20 questions? Cuz it is quite frankly an overkill, in the range 1-100 you'd probably only need around 10 questions in order for the program to guess the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't redeclare the variable `i` as `int`, you can just pass it in

```
switch (i)
```

Also, this isn't really a good use case for `switch` because you'd need:

```
switch (i)
{
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:     
    {
        cout << "int greater than 1, less than 5" << endl;
        break;
    }
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
    case 10:
    {
        cout << "int greater than 5 less than 10" << endl;
        break; 
    }
    ///...etc
}
```

You should really just use `if`, `else if`, `else`, such as:

```
if (i > 1 && i < 5)
{
    cout << "int greater than 1, less than 5" << endl;
}
else if (i >= 5 && i < 10)
{
    cout << "int greater than 5 less than 10" << endl;
}
else if (i >= 10)
{
    cout << "int greater than 10" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "int less than 2" << endl;
}
```

Also your `cout` statements are incorrect

```
cout << "int greater than 1, less than 5"; endl;
```

They should be

```
cout << "int greater than 1, less than 5" << endl;
```

Comment: is `case i > 1` valid?

Comment: @Creris: No, it is not. Only core  constant expressions are allowed.

Comment: one thing you could do in this case is `switch ((n-1)/5)` with `case` statements for 0, 1, and 2. Although that would give incorrect output for [-3,0]

Comment: Also, if you want to match the functionality the original code seemed to be aiming for, you would need that `else` to be `else if (i>10)` so that it won't print anything for `i<1`

Comment: After the last edit, if i == 5 it will still say it is less than 5 :) It is really an issue of the OP since his question doesn't really account for the possibility of 5, it is either less or more.

Comment: When using the else if statement can this be repeated repeated to create a large number of loops within loops? As said it isn't actually for the code this was just too learn how to use the switch function.